# how/why does writing to a volatile variable cause flushing of other variables?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading about concurrency in Java, including the `volatile` variable, for example here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html

The following quote is very interesting but I don't quite understand it yet:

> In effect, because the new memory model places stricter constraints on
>   reordering [by e.g. the processor for efficiency] of volatile field accesses with other field accesses,
>   volatile or not, anything that was visible to thread A when it writes
>   to volatile field f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f.

I already understood that a `volatile` variable cannot be cached in registers, so any write by any thread will be immediately visible by all other threads. Also according to this (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) reads and writes on volatile variables are atomic (not sure if that would include something like x++, but it's beside the point to this post).

But the quote I provided seems to imply something in addition to that. It says that **anything** visible to thread A will now be visible to thread B.

So just to make sure I have that right, does this mean that when a thread writes to a volatile variable, it does a full dump of its entire processor registers to main memory? Can you give some more context about how and why this happens? It might also help to compare/contrast this with synchronization (does it follow a similar mechanism or different?). Also, examples never hurt with something as complex as this :).

Comment: Are you trying to understand the specification or an implementation?

Comment: I guess you could say I'm trying to understand the spec, although it wouldn't hurt to mention different ways that the spec is implemented by way of example.

Comment: From what I understood here, if ThreadA publish at F and ThreadB reads from F after the volatile is read the others variables become visible.

Comment: As far as the spec, your understanding is correct. All writes in a thread prior to writing to a volatile variable will be visible to another thread after reading from the same variable. Synchronization has a similar effect. See the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) and [JCIP](http://jcip.net/) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

On x64, the JIT produced an instruction with a read or write barrier. The implementation is in hardware, not software.

> does this mean that when a thread writes to a volatile variable, it does a full dump of its entire processor registers to main memory?

No, only data written to memory is flushed. Not registers.

> Can you give some more context about how and why this happens?

The CPU implements this using an L2 cache coherency protocol (depending on the CPU)

Note: on a single cpu system, it doesn't need to do anything.

> It would also help to compare/contrast this with synchronization (does it follow a similar mechanism or different?).

It uses the same instructions.

> Also, examples never hurt with something as complex as this :).

When you read, it adds a read barrier.

When you write, it adds a write barrier.

The CPU then ensures the data stored in your L1 & L2 cache is appropriately synchronised with other CPUs.

Comment: Are my question correct?: "From what I understood here, if ThreadA publish at F and ThreadB reads from F after the volatile is read the others variables become visible. "

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This is exactly what happens. This is related to passing so called memory barrier. More details here: https://dzone.com/articles/memory-barriersfences